# Filtering of rows of pandas dataframe not working

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe

I have a following pandas dataframe:

```
In [23]: df
Out[23]: 
                                                 names
0                                        Alabama[edit]
1                        Auburn (Auburn University)[1]
2               Florence (University of North Alabama)
3      Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]
4           Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]
5             Montevallo (University of Montevallo)[2]
6                            Troy (Troy University)[2]
7    Tuscaloosa (University of Alabama, Stillman Co...
8                    Tuskegee (Tuskegee University)[5]
9                                         Alaska[edit]
10       Fairbanks (University of Alaska Fairbanks)[2]
11                                       Arizona[edit]
12          Flagstaff (Northern Arizona University)[6]
13                    Tempe (Arizona State University)
14                      Tucson (University of Arizona)
```

As you can see, some of the entries in `names` have the word `[edit]` in them. I want to filter only these entries and create a new dataframe out of it. So I tried:

```
In [24]: df1 = df[df['names'].str.contains("[edit]")]
```

However, the new dataframe `df1` doesn't give me what I want and still contains all the entries of the original dataframe:

```
In [25]: df1.head()
Out[25]: 
                                             names
0                                    Alabama[edit]
1                    Auburn (Auburn University)[1]
2           Florence (University of North Alabama)
3  Jacksonville (Jacksonville State University)[2]
4       Livingston (University of West Alabama)[2]
```

Exactly what am I missing and how can I fix it?

Comment: try this: `"\[edit\]"` instead of `"[edit]"` - `"[edit]"` is a RegEx giving you all strings containing any of those four characters: `['e','d','i','t']` or just use `regex=False` parameter

Comment: MaxU's solution will work. You may want to use `df[df['names'].str.endswith("[edit]")]`, will check for end parts of the string.

Comment: Worked! I still get confused with regex patterns.

Comment: Is there any way to modify this to find rows which do not contain a particular string? I don't see any method  in `str.contains`.

Comment: @Peaceful just add a bitwise not (`~`) infront: `df[~df['names'].str.contains("somestring")]` will return a dataframe with rows that don't contain `"somestring"` in column `names`.

Comment: btw, nice hat :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `str.extract` to parse, name column, and drop na's all at once

```
df.names.str.extract('(?P<names>.+)\[edit\]', expand=True).dropna()
```

[image]